# How to rename a method/field from Eclipse when not declared

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not a newbie of Java and Eclipse, this question is not as easy as `Alt`+`Shift`+`R` or `Refactor`>`Rename`

Assume there is a method in `utils.jar`.

```
public class A {
    public void taste() {} 
}
```

Then I used it in current project.

```
public class taste {
    public static void taste() {
        A taste = new A();
        return taste.taste(); 
    }
}
```

OK, now I found `taste` in `utils.jar` is not the word I want, then I changed the `utils.jar` to `test`:

```
public class A {
    public void test() {} 
}
```

So, after that, how could I change `A.taste()` to `A.test()` precisely just like use `Alt`+`Shift`+`R`?

```
public class taste {
    public static void taste() {
        A taste = new A();
        return taste.test();  // only change function A.taste to test
    }
}
```

I found that `Search`>`Java` can find the `A.taste` function precisely, but I have no idea how to replace all of it to `test`.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to rename a function inside a library which you are supposed to use as a blackbox. How about you consider using some kind of alias (basically wrapping a class around it) instead ?

Comment: you can move your mouse to the red underlined method name and press the `rename to xxx` option

Comment: @XtremeBaumer not as easy as that I think :-), i need to replace every references in my project, the example above is just a simplify scene

Comment: You would need the source code of the utils.jar to do this. Eclipse will not rename methods in a class file in a jar.

Comment: use `CTRL+H` > `File Search` then select `Replace...` at the bottom and there you go

Comment: @DuKes0mE it's hardly to perfection o(︶︿︶)o

Comment: @XtremeBaumer `File Search` will replace the class taste and static mothod taste of my project, the only thing i want to replace is A.taste to A.test

Comment: then search for A.taste and replace it with A.test

Comment: @XtremeBaumer `A taste = new A(); return taste.taste();` `A kkk = new A(); return kkk.taste()` `A helloworld = new A(); return helloworld.taste()`, it's hardly to replace it in pure text level, IDE should know the code structure first and then replace it like what `Alt`+`Shift`+`R` exactly does

Comment: I know its a bit of a hack, but I think this is the fastest solution: declare a new class `class A_enhanced extends A
{ 
   public void test() { super.taste(); }
}`. Then you can use the method `test()`

Comment: @DuKes0mE Thanks for your answer, but the only thing i need in this question is **how to rename a function that not defined** in eclipse. BTW your answer is helpful in real world case :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the old source code of `A` in your project. E.g. `src/some_package/A.java`

   This overrides the class from the library `utils.jar`
2. Use the refactoring tool to rename the method.

   You can do this now, because the source code of `A` is available
3. remove the source code of `A` from your project
4. add the updated lib `utils.jar` to your project

Comment: thank you, seems it's the only way to resolve it. I hope eclipse can support more functionality of refactor to rename the function/field not exists but developer can provide the signature manually.

Comment: It would be a nice feature if eclipse supports some kind of API migrations. E.g. if a method does not exist anymore in a new API it is a comiler error. But if the class still exists it might suggest a quick fix by displaying a dropdown list with applicable methods.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> might be useful in this case.

Comment: `Alt + Shift + R` is just like `Refactor` > `Rename` and is not work for this situation :-P